# How to playback an audio file with TheAmazingAudioEngine with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, the-amazing-audio-engine

I need to playback a **single audio file** with TheAmazingAudioEngine `framework` and `Swift`.
I'm completely newbie with this framework and tried the code below, but the audio didn't play. What is wrong? How could I play the audio file?

```
do {
    var audioController = AEAudioController(audioDescription: AEAudioController.nonInterleavedFloatStereoAudioDescription())
    let file = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myaudiofile", withExtension: "wav")!
    let channel = try AEAudioFilePlayer(URL: file)
    audioController?.addChannels([channel])
    channel.playAtTime(0)
} catch {
    print("Failure")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I missed to start the `audioController`:

```
do {
    var audioController = AEAudioController(audioDescription: AEAudioController.nonInterleavedFloatStereoAudioDescription())
    let file = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myaudiofile", withExtension: "wav")!
    let channel = try AEAudioFilePlayer(URL: file)
    audioController?.addChannels([channel])
    try audioController!.start()
} catch {
    print("Failure")
}
```